# Hexagonal hatched polygons Altium

Tags: pcb-design, altium, polygon, flex

I'm recently trying to design a flex PCB. I haven't been able to find any specific tutorials on how to do this in Altium. But I did find Altium blogs detailing some of the best design practices for rigid-flex PCBs.

One thing that I haven't been able to replicate is the hexagonal hatch that they say enhances flexibility. I've trying to do this through polygon pour without any luck.

I would like to know if anyone has managed to achieve this type of hatch! Thanks!

[image]

Comment: This would be a great suggestion for Altium's "Ideas" page, since I don't believe they currently support it: https://bugcrunch.live.altium.com/#Ideas/New

Comment: Altium has an excellent (if poorly documented) scripting system.  A script to generate such a hatch would be not too difficult to write.  Or, generate in a 2D drawing program and import it as copper traces.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to achieve a hexagonal hatch by using a solid polygon pour, and a series of hexagonal polygon pour cutouts. Its not the quickest or most accurate, but without knowledge of scripting or some complicated import process, its the simplest way to do it.

Start by drawing a hexagon with lines, (you may need to do some trigonometry to be accurate) then use the polygon pour cutout to go over it, and then a lot of copy and pasting.

[image]